# How can I select lastest purchase price before a selling date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 5 tables in my database, products, purchase_orders, invoice, invoice_details, and product_prices and their schema are like below.

```
Table: products
id
trade_name

Table: purchase_orders
id
product_id
created

Table: invoices
id
created

Table invoice_details
id
invoice_id
product_id
price_id

Table product_prices
id
retail_price
effective_from
effective_to
```

I think that I need to somehow join or check created on purchase_orders to created on invoices. So, I started with getting drug id, invoice date.

```
select  d.id as drug_id
        , i.created as invoice_created
        , dp.retail_price
from    drugs d
inner join  invoice_details id
        on d.id = id.drug_id
inner join  invoices i
        on i.id = id.invoice_id
inner join  drug_prices dp
        on dp.id = id.price_id
```

The next step is to match created on invoice that I have to created on purchase_orders which I haven't figured it out.

```
inner join  (
            select      drug_id
                    , purchase_price
                    , ISNULL(created, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-10-07 01:37:12.370')) as created
            from        purchase_orders po
            ) as prepared_po
            on prepared_po.created <= i.created
```

How can I get the lasted purchase price for each item that I sold?

Comment: Why did I get a downvote for this question?

Comment: It might be helpful if you add some example data and expected results to your query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version of the logic you need (I renamed your columns so that it's easier to see which are which without doing all the intermediary joins you've already written yourself):

```
;With CTE as (select a.productID, a.saledate, b.price, b.purchasedate
  , row_number() over (partition by a.productID, a.saledate 
                       order by b.purchasedate desc) RN
from sales a 
left join purchases b
on a.productID = b.productID and a.saledate >= b.purchasedate
)

Select productID, saledate, price, purchasedate 
from CTE where RN = 1
```

Basically, you join to get all purchase records up to the sale date, then use `row_number` to find the latest one.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0f68/2/0